# Solution for non-blocking timer and server is boost threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer

My project has a queue, a server and a timer. The server receives data and puts it in the queue and the timer process the queue. When the queue is processed, external processes are open with popen, which means that popen will block the timer until a process has ended.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as both server and timer are linked to the same io_service, if the server receives data, it will somehow block io_service from proceeding to the next event, and the vice-versa is the timer blocking if a process in the queue is being executed.

I'm thinking  in a solution based on boost::thread but I'm not sure of what architecture should I use as I never used threads. My options are:

Two threads - one for the timer and one for the server, each one using its own io_service
One thread - one for the timer with its own io_service. the server remains in main process

In both ways the queue (a simple map) must be shared, so I think I'll have some trouble with mutexes and other things

If someone wants to take a look at the code, it is at https://github.com/MendelGusmao/CGI-for-LCD-Smartie

Thanks!

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146566/blocking-queue-for-thread-producer-consumers-for-win32-c

Comment: @MendelGusmao - Did any of the below answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't have your server listening for connections, processing data, and placing that data in the queue in one thread while your timer takes those items out of the queue in another thread and then spawns processes via `popen()` to process the queue data.  Unless there is a detail here that I've missed, the socket that the server will be listening on (or pipe, FIFO, etc.), is separate from the pipe that will be internally opened by the libc runtime via `popen()`, so your server and timer threads won't be blocking each other.  You'll simply have to make sure that you have enough space in the queue to store the data coming in from the server without overflowing memory (i.e., if this is a high-data-rate application, and data is coming in much faster than it's being processed, you'll eventually run out of memory).

Finally, while guarding a shared queue via muextes is a good thing, it's actually unnecessary for only a single producer/consumer situation like you're currently describing if you decide to use a bounded queue (i.e., a ring-buffer).  If you decide on an unbounded queue, while there are some lockless algorithms out there, they're pretty complex, and so guarding an unbounded queue like `std::queue<T>` with a mutex is an absolute must.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented almost the exact thing you have described using windows threads. I had my consumer wait on an event `HANDLE` which is fired by the producer when the queue gets too long. There was a timeout on the wait as well so that if the queue was not filled fast enough the consumer would still wait and process the queue. It was a service in windows so the main thread was used for that. And yes, mutexes will be required to access the shared object.

So I used two threads (not including the main), 1 mutex, 1 shared object. I think your better option is also two threads as it keeps the logic cleaner. The main thread just starts the two threads and then waits (or can be used for signalling, control, output), and the two other threads are just doing their own jobs.